# How do I make the extension shortcut the priority in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

I want to assign an extension action to Alt + T but even though it's set properly, Firefox is still overriding it and showing its own mini menu instead of activating the extension action.

[image]

How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Firefox is still overriding it and showing its own mini menu

That's because Firefox uses <kbd>alt</kbd> as a shortcut to open the menu bar and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will open the tools menu.

There are a couple of potential fixes.

> **How to disable menu popping up when I press ALT key**
>
> You can set the `ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses` pref to false on the
> `about:config` page to prevent opening the menu when holding down the
> Alt key. This may require to close and restart Firefox.
>
> ```
> ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses = false
> ```
>
> You can open the `about:config` page via the location/address bar. You
> can accept the warning and click "I accept the risk!" to continue.

Source: [How to disable menu popping up when I press ALT key](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1278533)

If you still wants access to the menu bar you can change the shortcut uses to open it:

> **How to disable menu bar navigation via alt+_ key shortcuts?**
>
> set `ui.key.menuAccessKey = 17` on the `about:config` page. This makes
> the menu bar work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Source: [How to disable menu bar navigation via alt+_ key shortcuts?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1286628)

Comment: Amazing, I didn't even know the popup was coming from the menu bar since I thought it was inactive when hidden. I just thought it was a random quick access menu of sorts.

Comment: Just an update, `ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses` set to `false` with a browser restart did not work. What DID work was setting `ui.key.menuAccessKey` to `0`